# Convert float column into string and test presence of string in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have this dataframe:

```
   cnpj             Porte
0  453232000125 
1  11543123000156
2  345676
3  121234561023456
```

'cnpj' is currently as float.

If cnpj has '0001' in it, I want to classify 'Porte' as A. So it looks like this:

```
   cnpj             Porte
0  453232000125     A
1  11543123000156   A
2  345676
3  121234561023456
```

I'm trying:

```
 df['Porte'].loc[(df['cnpj'].astype(int).astype(str).str.contains('0001'))]='A'
```

But it gets me this error:

```
TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'int'>
```

How could I do that?

Comment: it's working my solution for you ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one approach.

**Demo:**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({"cnpj": [453232000125, 11543123000156, 345676]})
df["Porte"] = df["cnpj"].apply(lambda x: "A" if '0001' in str(x) else np.nan)
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
             cnpj Porte
0    453232000125     A
1  11543123000156     A
2          345676   NaN
```

Answer (score 2):

Another approach:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"cnpj": [453232000125, 11543123000156, 345676, 121234561023456]})
df['Porte'] = np.where(df['cnpj'].astype(str).str.contains('0001'), 'A', '')
```

Output:

```
              cnpj Porte
0     453232000125     A
1   11543123000156     A
2           345676      
3  121234561023456
```

Answer (score 1):

You were very close. Just remove `astype(int)` statement.

```
df['Porte'].loc[(df['cnpj'].astype(str).str.contains('0001')]='A'
```

The second parameter passed to `loc` method also could be the `column` you want to update and below is another way to achieve your requirement.

```
df.loc[df['cnpj'].astype(str).str.contains('0001'), 'Porte'] = "A"
```